# Drawerlayout opendrawer NullpointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm using DrawerLayout for Navigation between different fragments. But in my application I'm not using toolbar, for toolbar I created a linear layout which is included in each fragment's layout and define Drawer layout publicly static in my main activity for accessing it from each fragment.And my drawerlayout is in main_activity.xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- Profile Box -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_material2"
            android:padding="8dp" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/user2"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="42dp"

                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"

                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sushant Kumar"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

                    android:text="8931839445"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/alert"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Getting Problems while connecting to Server."
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my main activity I initialize like this :

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
    mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my toolbar xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ABOUT MOOVO"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here on click of Ic_menu icon I open the drawer pane from different fragments using this code :

```
Ic_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(MainActivity.mDrawerPane);
        }
    });
```

This working properly most of time but sometimes this give Nullpointerexception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

How to solve this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you initialize your mDrawerLayout using?

  mDrawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.<whatever id you gave to drawerlayout>)

Answer (score 0):

If your `Ic_menu.setOnClickListener()` is not in the MainActivity then you can  inflate xml of Mainactivity in current activity and initialize all views there.
code:

```
 View view = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

       mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
```

Now your updated `Ic_menu.setOnClickListener()` should look like this:

```
Ic_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerPane);
        }
    });
```

Comment: still Not working, I'm calling drawerlayout from fragments which comes in mainContent Framelayout

Comment: still getting NullPointer?

Comment: No, drawer layout not open on click event

Comment: Your main question was about null pointer and it is solved so you should mark as correct green arrow  and upvote for solution of your null pointer problem so, other user can find solution for their problem.

Comment: But new issue is created after that solution

Comment: Code you provided in the question doesn't contain new issue, if you would have solved null pointer without my solution still this issue will arrive, so that is not in my scope. Everytime you do code issues will raise, respect answers which solves your problems. No one can solve your whole application.